# android insmod init_module failed (required key not available)

Tags: android, linux, insmod

can some one help me?

I have run imsmod like this:

```
$ insmod /data/mm/mmdev.ko epoll_rate=100
```

but I got an error:

```
insmod: init_module failed (required key not available)
```

I googled it a lot, but there is no a perfect answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because mmdev.ko module is signed.
You can check if module is signed or not using command
readelf -S mmdev.ko   | grep module_sig

If it is signed, try to remove module signature using following commands
1. objcopy -R .note.module_sig mmdev.ko OR
   objcopy -R .module_sig mmdev.ko
2. Check again output of : readelf -S mmdev.ko   | grep module_sig
3. Now check with command: # insmod /data/mm/mmdev.ko epoll_rate=100

Comment: What if it's not signed(meaning I don't have module_sig inside that module)?